# MVC5/C#: Pass LINQ inner Join query to view model

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to pass data(.tolist) in inner join query to viewmodel, to use these data in view that contain also a partial view that needs data from viewModel.

```
public ActionResult IndexAdmin()
{
    int userId = (int)Session["UserID"];
    userInfo = _context.UserInfo.Find(userId);    

    var AllTours= (from p in _context.PostsInfo  //Why this doesn't return two records
                           join r in _context.Region
                           on p.RegionId equals r.Id
                           where r.CountryId == 1
                           select new
                           {
                              RegionName = r.CountryId,
                              ImageName = p.ImageName,

                           }).Distinct().ToList(); 



//Here i need to define IndexAdminViewModel to populate tours and userInfo.username 

    return View(AllTours);
}
```

This is the IndexAdminViewModel:

```
 public class IndexAdminViewModel
 {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string RegionName{get;set;}
    public string ImageName {get;set;}
 }
```

The view(IndexAdmin.cshtml)

```
@Html.Partial("_BarPartialAdmin", Model)

foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <img src="~/images/@post.ImageName" alt="QfirstImage">
    <h2>post.RegionName</h2>

}
```

The partial view will only needs the username to display it for once so i used to pass the model to partial view in order to use the username property, the RegionName and ImageName is a collection so that i can iterate over them and get teh values some way like use them in a table.

**My question is how to pass the inner join query results AND theuserinfo.username to viewModel to use them in the view???????**

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My question is how to pass the inner join query AND the userinfo.username to viewModel to use them in the view

Comment: Your view model does not contain a property named `RegionName` and `ImageName`. And what is `AllQatarTours`? No idea what your trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I update the question but how to populate the two properties from the query to the viewmodel and then populate the userInfo.username to the username property in viewmodel

Comment: And what are your properties `Region` and `PostsInfo` for and how do you want to populate them?

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry i'm new to mvc what i want from these two properties is to use them in populating in some how?? 
Main question is how to populate RegionName, ImageName  and the username

Comment: `var model = new IndexAdminViewModel(){ UserName = userInfo.username, RegionName = AllTours.RegionName, etc }; return View(model);`. But that only works if you use `.FirstOrDefault()`, not `.Distinct().ToList();` (which is returning a collection)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the question with screenshot of the query result. I need to user the `toList()` because in the view i will iterate the results and show them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142175/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fares-ayyad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create 2 view models

```
public class ToursViewModel
{
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string ImageName {get; set; }  
}
public class IndexAdminViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ToursViewModel> Tours {get;set;}
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult IndexAdmin()
{
    int userId = (int)Session["UserID"];
    userInfo = _context.UserInfo.Find(userId);    

    IEnumerable<ToursViewModel> tours = (
        from p in _context.PostsInfo
        join r in _context.Region
        on p.RegionId equals r.Id
        where r.CountryId == 1
        select new ToursViewModel
        {
            RegionName = r.CountryId,
            ImageName = p.ImageName
        });
    IndexAdminViewModel model = new IndexAdminViewModel
    {
        UserName = userInfo.username,
        Tours = tours
    };
    return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model IndexAdminViewModel
....
<h1>@Model.UserName</h1>
@foreach (var tour in Model.Tours)
{
    <img src="~/images/@tour.ImageName" alt="QfirstImage">
    <h2>@tour.RegionName</h2>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I you need to pass different objects to the view you basically have two options:

1. Create a composite class and use that as model

   ```
   var allTours= 
       from p in _context.PostsInfo  //Why this doesn't return two records
       join r in _context.Region
       on p.RegionId equals r.Id
       where r.CountryId == 1
       select new PostAndRegion
       {
         Region = r.CountryId,
         Post= p.ImageName,
       };
   var model = new MyCompositeModel 
   {
        PostsAndRegions = allTours.ToArray(),
        UserInfo = null // or get from where you want to
   };
   return View(model);
   ```

with

```
    public class PostAndRegion
    {
        public Post Post{get;set;}
        public Region Region {get;set;}
    }

    public class MyCompositeModel
    {
        public IList<PostAndRegion> PostsAndRegions{get;set;}
        public UserInfo MyUserInfo{get;set;}
    }
```

2. Put some of the data in the ViewBag. see http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: public class PostAndRegion { Post Post {get;set;} Region {get;set;}}

select new PostAndRegion{Post = p, Region = r }
ToArray()